# How to make a div that is a child of a table cell responsive to td size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get divs that are contained within table cells (tr, td format) to scale with the responsive table sizing. This is my current code: 
<--Styling-->

```
table {
    border: 3px solid;
    width: 30%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;

    table-layout: fixed;
}
table td {
  width: 12.5%;
  padding-bottom: 12.5%; 
}
.piece-image {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

<--HTML-->

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <div class="piece-image">
         <img src="/rk_wht.png/">
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

EDIT: I'm using position:absolute so that the divs sit within the td without effect the size of the cell, any other way and the divs seem to turn the cells from squares into rectangles. I am making a chessboard with this layout.

For some reason, the div containing the image wont resize with the responsive table cells, which resize great and stay squares. The end result is a chessboard with 60x60 px images in the image element. Not sure if maybe images can't get smaller past a certain size, or what is keeping the div from being responsive.

Comment: Don't make it absolutely positioned, try relative position

Comment: The issue there is then the size of the div gets added to the size of the td, so the table goes from squares to rectangles.

Comment: Then try giving the td elements relative position, because absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to the nearest positioned parent or table element, if none is found, it's the body

Comment: I gave the td relative and set the divs to absolute, and added a class to the images themselves and made them width: 100% height: auto, and it works great now! Thanks a ton for your input, you lead me to the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do

```
position:relative
```

Comment: I have position absolute because any other way, the div height gets added to the td height instead of siting inside of the td and keeping the square shape. position:relative turns the squares into rectangles.